# Type Error: Format Requires Mapping

Tags: python, string, list, object, dictionary

I have a string and a list of objects:

```
gpl = "%(id)s : %(atr)s"

objects = [{'id':1, 'content':[{'atr':'big', 'no':2}]},  {'id':2, 'content': [{'atr':'small', 'no':3}]}]

for obj in objects:
   for con in obj['content']:
       print gpl %(obj,con)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

How would I print this? I am trying to print:

```
1 : big
2 : small
```

Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since your formatting string uses named parameters:

```
gpl = "%(id)s : %(atr)s"
```

You need to provide keys (the names) in a dictionary as an argument to reference back to named formatting keys in the formatting string:

```
print gpl % {'id': obj['id'], 'atr': con['atr']}
```

So your code would be:

```
for obj in objects:
    for con in obj['content']:
        print gpl% {'id': obj['id'], 'atr': con['atr']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn `obj` and `con` into one dictionary - your current code passes in a `tuple`.

If you don't care what happens to `objects` afterwards, use [dict.update](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
for obj in objects:
    for con in obj["content"]:
        con.update(obj)
        print gpl % con

1 : big
2 : small
```

If you don't want `objects` modified, you'll need to build an intermediate dictionary:

```
for obj in objects:
    for con in obj["content"]:
        print gpl % {'id': obj["id"], 'atr': con["atr"]}

1 : big
2 : small
```